# how to check if NFS is installed or working RHEL

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, redhat

I have put  the following line  on /etc/exports

```
/media/drive/fedora     *(ro , sync)
```

then i did

```
exportfs -a
```

now my hostname is  localhost.fedora

i want to install the linux from NFS but when i enter the
hostname and foldername it says folder can't be mounted.

How can i check that NFS is working and also how will the new machine will know the ip of

localhost.fedora

Comment: Why do you want your account deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Your question could really do with some more clarity. Apparently you have two machines. A NFS server and another that you're trying to install fedora to.

You should be able to specify the server to the installer by IP address. To check that NFS is working, try mounting it locally on the server. I.e. `mount -t nfs localhost:/media/drive/fedora /mnt`

Comment: i tried that and got this error  

mount: mount to NFS server 'localhost' failed: RPC Error: Program not registered.

Comment: Is the NFS server configured to also be able to act as an NFS client? Do you have rpc.mountd and rpc.statd running?